# How to get ls like output using find command

Tags: command-line, find

I am trying to get `ls` like output from find command (this is on Linux Mind with `find (GNU findutils) 4.7.0`.

This is because I want to see the [numerical chmod permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1796163/1772898).

What I managed so far is:

```
% find . -maxdepth 1 -printf "%m %M %y %g %G %u %U %f %l\n"
755 drwxr-xr-x d blueray 1000 blueray 1000 . 
664 -rw-rw-r-- f blueray 1000 blueray 1000 .zshrc 
644 -rw-r--r-- f blueray 1000 blueray 1000 .gtkrc-xfce 
644 -rw-r--r-- f blueray 1000 blueray 1000 .sudo_as_admin_successful 
777 lrwxrwxrwx l root 0 root 0 resolv.conf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

Here, `%l` print empty string if file is not a symbolic link.

What I am looking for is, if `%l` is not empty then print `-> %l`.

How can I do that with `-printf`?

Comment: This might help with GNU find: `find -maxdepth 1 -ls`

Comment: @Cyrus yeah, my first thought too but that doesn't show the octal file permissions which is what the OP is doing this for.

Comment: If what you care about is the permissions, I'd get that directly from GNU `stat` (which can be told to emit them via its more-expressive format string syntax).

Comment: Given your real use case, is there any reason you're asking for `ls`-like output, instead of just asking for numerical permissions and filenames (and potentially nothing else)?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `stats` do not show hidden files, at least on my machine. Otherwise I could make `ls` like output from `stats` (https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat).

Comment: @blueray, `stat` doesn't list files at all -- it requires something else to give it the list. So, f/e, in `stat *`, it's not `stat` deciding what files are included in `*`, it's your shell making that decision; you can make your shell include hidden files in `*` by changing its configuration, or you can tell `find` to pass filenames to `stat` with something like `find . -exec stat ... {} +`, substituting `...` with the arguments you choose.

Comment: @blueray, (...and btw, it's singular, `stat`, not `stats`; the command is named after the underlying syscall).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can tell `find` to print one thing for links and another for non links. For example:

```
$ find  . -maxdepth 1 \( -not -type l -printf "%m %M %y %g %G %u %U %f\n" \) -or \( -type l -printf "%m %M %y %g %G %u %U %f -> %l\n" \) 
755 drwxr-xr-x d terdon 1000 terdon 1000 .
644 -rw-r--r-- f terdon 1000 terdon 1000 file1
755 drwxr-xr-x d terdon 1000 terdon 1000 dir
644 -rw-r--r-- f terdon 1000 terdon 1000 file
777 lrwxrwxrwx l terdon 1000 terdon 1000 linkToFile -> file
```

Or, a little more legibly:

```
find  . -maxdepth 1 \( -not -type l -printf "%m %M %y %g %G %u %U %f\n" \) \
                -or \( -type l -printf "%m %M %y %g %G %u %U %f -> %l\n" \)
```

The `\( -not -type l -printf '' ... \)` will be run for anything that isn't a symlink, while the `-or \( -type l -printf '' ...\)` will be run for symlinks only.

Comment: Or you could pipe it to `xargs stat`

Comment: @waltinator, `find ... | xargs stat` is quite severely buggy, unless you mean `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 stat`. By default, `xargs` treats quotes and backslashes as syntactic rather than literal, word-splits on spaces, provides no means _whatsoever_ to escape literal newlines, and otherwise can't correctly handle a wide variety of legitimate file names. Better to just use `find ... -exec stat ... {} +`, so `find` itself is running `stat` (using `{} +` instead of `{} \;` buys one the same performance benefits `xargs` provides in terms of running the fewest necessary copies of `stat`)